# How many people did Al Capone kill?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, crime, statistics

How many deaths was Al Capone responsible for? Including people killed by his order or as part of gang wars he started? (Looking for an estimate within an order of magnitude).

Comment: It seems to me that the answer is going to have to be an estimate.  Given that records of either of the activities would have been very likely to lead to a death sentence, I doubt that records were created or kept, I'm skeptical that we have records of the deaths he ordered, and very skeptical that we can identify which gang wars he started.  Are gang wars discrete events that are susceptible to observation and study?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I'm fine with an estimate up to an order of magnitude.

Comment: The site [alcaponebio.com](http://alcaponebio.com) discusses 12; wikipedia lists (based on an article by Guy Murchie) 33. At a guess I'd say less than 50, even including those murdered in his name, but not by his orders. Who is he going to kill? He gave explicit orders to his gang NOT to kill, or even rough up law enforcement/feds. He killed his own kind (whom he thought betrayed him) and rivals. Organized crime was big during prohibition, but not THAT big.

Comment: *How many people did Al Capone kill ?* - Not enough.